# SQLite table updation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, mysql, ios5

I want to update my sqlite table through query:

```
UPDATE animals SET name = 'kangaroo' WHERE id = '9'
```

My query runs normally without error but my table was not updated so i checked the code returned by mysql_step() and it returns 5 which means my database is busy. I have used the database connection in many classes in my project. I also checked that i have closed the connection properly or not. Than why this database busy response is coming? Please help i spend a lot of time with this problem and was unable to sort out the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is going to be one simple answer, as there is no simple question. The update query is fine; as you suggest, it is the complexity of the relationships within the app which matter. You will have to break it down until it works, then build it back up carefully.